# cannot recover windows8 after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grub2, windows

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and since then I haven't been able to dualboot to Windows 8. I have tried `boot-repair` to create a file `30_windows`, still nothing seems to work. The generated log after boot repair is: http://paste2.org/7e86y4zL

Any help, please?

Comment: You might want to use http://paste.ubuntu.com. Your link to the paste is not working.

Comment: I fixed his link, the log shows up now. :)

Comment: Nishan, do you have access to the Windows 8 installation DVD? That may help in solving the issue faster.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a UEFI capable machine, running Windows 8 in legacy mode on an MSdos partition table disk got an UEFI Ubuntu install, instead of a legacy mode install (you select the mode in the BIOS/UEFI settings). There is an EFI partition at the end of the disk, sda8, but it contains no bootloaders, neither Ubuntu, nor Windows, but it now has the boot flag.  Fix one, move the boot flag back to the Windows partition, sda2 from sda8 (Ubuntu does not care, but Windows does).  Boot Ubuntu (in legacy mode), and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and see if you get a Windows choice in the grub menu.  Try it and see if it works.

---

Check which grub you have installed, an UEFI install will leave you with the wrong one, grub-pc is needed for legacy, not grub-efi-amd64.

```
dpkg -l |grep grub
```

You can purge and reinstall the grub packages, or just reinstall in the correct legacy mode, formatting the existing Ubuntu partition.  That gets rid of any changes you made to the /etc/grub.d files too.

Comment: I did update the grub too.. It can't find the windows either.. Only Linux images are found